# Android Studio "Untrusted Server's Certificate"

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, server

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gwf1K.png)

This keeps popping up occasionally while not doing anything specific. From Wuhan, China? I've pressed 'Reject' a few times but after a few minutes it reappears. Is this safe? My project is connected to Google Firebase.

Comment: interesting, is the android studio was downloaded from official android website? https://developer.android.com/studio

Comment: Yes, it is from https://developer.android.com/studio

Comment: have you try to delete `cacerts` file in the path sown in your screenshot?

Comment: No but now that I tried the directory where it says it should be is empty. I have show hidden files enabled

Comment: Do you have a Huawei router by any chance in your home network?

Comment: No but the smartphone I am connected to via usb for debugging is a Huawei! Could that be it?

Comment: @JacobEriksson I guess it could be. As much as I can find on the forums is that usually this is created by routers made by Huawei and they are just inspecting your traffic, nothing serious. Try disconnecting your device and testing it with AVD or something and check if it will show up again. If not then your phone is doing this and accepting this certificate won't cause any issues as much as I know.